# oauth tokens using JMeter

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, authorization, access-token

I am not sure if this is even a valid question or not, but, is there a way we can generate the authorization & access tokens (oauth 2.0) using JMeter?

JMeter version - 5.4.1

NOTE : oauth Sampler plugin in JMeter is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of simple [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/), just replicate the [OAuth Flow](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) in terms of [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) from browser (or other application) using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers  and extract the dynamic values from the responses using suitable [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), most probably you will need [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

---

Some OAuth providers offer Java Client SDKs and you can authenticate using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and invoke the authorization functions offered by the SDK

Answer (score 0):

Using WDS(Web driver sampler)-Javascript and jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config
In jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config under options enter --remote-allow-origins=* and under Driver give the path of chromedriver exe file without .exe extension in case of MAC

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jp4E.png)

```js
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
var conditions = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(120))
var jmeterVariables = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

WDS.browser.get(jmeterVariables.get('url'));

var userName = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@class='amplify-input amplify-field-group__control' and @name='username']")); 
userName.click();
userName.sendKeys([jmeterVariables.get('userName')]);  

var password = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@class='amplify-input amplify-field-group__control' and @name='password']")); 
password.click(); 
password.sendKeys([jmeterVariables.get('password')]); 

var signInbutton = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//button[@class='amplify-button amplify-button--primary amplify-field-group__control amplify-authenticator__font']")); 
signInbutton.click();

wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.cssSelector('.p-menuitem-link.router-link-active.router-link-active-exact')))

var dashboard=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector('.p-menuitem-link.router-link-active.router-link-active-exact')).getText()
WDS.log.info("Dashboard text " +dashboard);

var tokenStorageValue  = WDS.browser.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.getItem("auth-mod")')
WDS.log.info("Token storage value is " +tokenStorageValue);

var value = JSON.parse(tokenStorageValue);
jmeterVariables.put('token',value.userToken);
WDS.log.info("User Token Value is " +value.userToken);
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```